# Extending a short hand ambient module import in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a concise way of extended an import from a declaration.

I tried the following, but got an error of: `error TS2507: Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.` Example code is below:

**base.d.ts**

```
declare module 'base';
```

**derived.ts**

```
import * as Base from 'base';

class Derived extends Base { // error TS2507: Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorthand ambient modules are good only for values, not for types.

This does not compile too, and I don't think it comes as a surprise:

```
import * as Base from 'base';

interface X {
    foo: Base.Foo;//error TS2694: Namespace ''base'' has no exported member 'Foo'
}


function f(s: string) {}

f(Base.Foo);  // note: no error here, for the same Base.Foo
```

Shorthand modules were introduced as a way to say that "everything inside has `any` type". There is no analog of `any` for classes and types - you can't extend a class without having complete declaration for it.

Comment: Yeah, I had to do this: 
  ` declare module 'base' {
     interface Constructor {
         new (...args: any[]): this;
     }

     const _: Constructor;
     export = _;
   }`